# Quitting a GTK popup window properly

Tags: memory-leaks, gtk3

I am not sure if there may be a memory leak here - its about quitting a simple  popup window in GTK.

```
if (alertWindow == NULL) {
    alertWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    alertLabel = gtk_label_new (" wrong input! connection should be either s,S,p or P.\n All other data as floating numbers" );
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(alertWindow), alertLabel);
    g_signal_connect (alertWindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroyAlert), NULL); //avslutar applikation
}
```

and the callback

```
static void destroyAlert(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
   alertWindow = NULL;
}
```

I set the alertWindow to NULL so it can be created once again next time the user enters wrong input.

Answer (score 1):

That should not leak memory. The window assumes a reference to the label, so the label will get destroyed and freed with the window. The window will get destroyed and freed when you click on the window title bar's close button (which is the only way to close that window according to the code that you have.)

However, I'd suggest doing it a different way:

```
GtkWidget *alertWindow = gtk_message_dialog_new(parentWindow,
    GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT | GTK_DIALOG_USE_HEADER_BAR,
    GTK_MESSAGE_WARNING, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
    "Wrong input! Connection should be either s, S, p or P.\n"
    "All other data as floating point numbers.");
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(alertWindow));
gtk_widget_destroy(alertWindow);
```

This has a few advantages; first, you get a more full-featured dialog with a friendly button for closing it. Second, you don't have to use a global variable that you then have to worry about whether it is NULL or not. Third, the dialog is modal (the rest of the application is disabled while the dialog is open), which is appropriate for an error message like this.

Even better would be to detect the wrong input as the user types, and use something like a GtkPopover to inform them of what kind of input belongs in each field.